# How to remove quotation marks from variable that writes to a file?

Tags: python

Everytime i run this part code everything goes smoothly BUT when it writes the variable to the file it shows up with quotation marks, is there a way to remove them and write it as simple text?

```
try:
        with open(tokens) as f:                 
            lines = f.readlines()               
            answer = random.choice(lines)       
            print(answer)                       
    except:

    file_name = tokens                      
    opened_file = open(tokens, 'a')         
    opened_file.write("%r\n" %user_input)   
    opened_file.close()
```

writing in the file looks like this:
'Whats up'
and i want it to look like this:
Whats up

Comment: If its a string then try using `%s` instead of `%r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your line that writes to the log you are using %r as your format in the string. the Python docs say

> Replacing %s and %r:
>
> > > >
> > >
> > > > "repr() shows quotes: {!r}; str() doesn't: {!s}".format('test1', 'test2') "repr() shows quotes: 'test1'; str() doesn't: test2"

So replace this line

```
opened_file.write("%r\n" %user_input)
```

with

```
opened_file.write("%s\n" %user_input)
```